# If $\tan(\alpha/2) = m$, then evaluate $\frac{1-2\sin^2(\alpha/2)}{1+\sin\alpha}$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2}) =  m $ then evaluate :
>   $$ \frac{1-2\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{1+\sin \alpha} $$

How to evaluate this?

I am  new to half - angles in trigonometry.

I learnt : $\tan (x/2) =  ±\sqrt{ \frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x} } $, but
I was unable to proceed.

Comment: What have you learnt and what have you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that by the [addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for the cosine
$$\cos \alpha =\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2})=\cos^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})=1-2\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})$$
which implies  that$2\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})=1-\cos(\alpha)$.

Then use the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) (which follows from your formula $m^2= \frac{1-\cos \alpha}{1+\cos \alpha}$):
$$\cos\alpha =\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}\quad,\quad \sin\alpha =\frac{2m}{1+m^2}.$$

Comment: See the formula in my ques., is it ?

Comment: From your formula, you get $m^2= \frac{1-\cos \alpha}{1+\cos \alpha} $. 
 Use the link that I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

If a right triangle with angle $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ has opposite side length $m$ and adjacent side length $1$, then its hypotenuse is $\sqrt{m^2 + 1}$.  Thus,

$$\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2}) = \pm \frac{m}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}}$$
$$\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}) = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}}$$

Where the signs must match in order to have $\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2}) = \frac{\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})} = m$ instead of $-m$.

Then $\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2}) = \frac{m^2}{m^2 + 1}$, with the $\pm$ eliminated by the squaring, and $\sin(\alpha) = \sin(2\frac{\alpha}{2}) = 2\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}) = \frac{2m}{m^2 + 1}$, with the matching signs of the factors again taking care of the $\pm$ for us.  Thus,

$$\frac{1-2\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{1+\sin \alpha}$$
$$= \frac{1-2\frac{m^2}{m^2 + 1}}{1+\frac{2m}{m^2 + 1}}$$
$$= \frac{m^2 + 1 - 2m^2}{m^2 + 1 + 2m}$$
$$= \frac{1-m^2}{m^2+2m+1}$$
$$= \frac{(1+m)(1-m)}{(m+1)^2}$$
$$= \frac{1-m}{1+m}$$